# Convert XML element into attribute in T- SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I need to query a SQL table and output data into this XML format. can someone help out or point me into t he right direction.

Note: I need to use T-SQL to achieve this result.

```
<account>
    <field name="A" value="aaaaaaaa" type="string"/>
    <field name="B" value="bbbbbbbbb" type="string"/>
    <field name="I" value="11111111" type="int"/>
</account>
```

Comment: what's the db engine? version?

Comment: He says t-SQL so its got to be SQL Server.